# How to see page breaks in Numbers version 3.x

Tags: numbers

In my old version of Numbers, I could see the page break (both at the bottom of the page, and on the side) so I would know when I needed to add a row or column. I can't seem to be able to see the page break anymore: I need to go to print preview in order to get a sense of where rows and columns are on the page. 
Is there a way to see the page break in the new version?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Apple's Numbers has never had page breaks.  Here is a solution created from Yellowbox on the Apple's Community forum: https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-7101.

Here is also a answer from Ian, also on Apple's forums--

"Numbers has never had Page Breaks.

If you are using Numbers '09 it has Show Print View which is useful for arranging (and resizing) objects on pages before you print to paper.

If you are using Numbers 3, there is only Menu > Print > Print Preview (Print Setup) which shows the pages, but is not editable."